# Scrapy: How to find highest/lowest values from a number of values?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to write a crawler using Scrapy/Python, that reads some values from a page.

I then want this crawler to store the highest and lowest values in seperate fields.

So far, I am able to read the values from the page (please see my code below), but I am not sure how to calculate the  lowest and highest value and store in separate fields ?

For example, say the crawler reads the page and returns these values

- t1-score = 75.25
- t2-score = 85.04
- t3-score = '' (value missing)
- t4-score = 90.67
- t5-score = 50.00

So I want to populate ....

- 'highestscore': 90.67
- 'lowestscore':  50.00

How do I do that ? Do I need to use an array ? Put all values in array and then pick the highest/lowest ?

Any help is very appreciated.

**Here is my code so far ....** I am storing -1, in case of missing values.

```
 class MySpider(BaseSpider):
            name = "courses"
            start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/courses-listing']
            allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
            def parse(self, response):
             hxs = Selector(response)
             for courses in response.xpath("//meta"):
             {
             d = {
                 'courset1score': float(courses.xpath('//meta[@name="t1-score"]/@content').extract_first('').strip() or -1),
                 'courset2score': float(courses.xpath('//meta[@name="t2-score"]/@content').extract_first('').strip() or -1),
                 'courset3score': float(courses.xpath('//meta[@name="t3-score"]/@content').extract_first('').strip() or -1),
                 'courset4score': float(courses.xpath('//meta[@name="t4-score"]/@content').extract_first('').strip() or -1),
                 'courset5score': float(courses.xpath('//meta[@name="t5-score"]/@content').extract_first('').strip() or -1),
                 }
             d['highestscore'] = max(d.values())
             d['lowestscore'] = min(d.values())
             'pagetitle': courses.xpath('//meta[@name="pagetitle"]/@content').extract_first(),
             'pageurl': courses.xpath('//meta[@name="pageurl"]/@content').extract_first(),
             }

             for url in hxs.xpath('//ul[@class="scrapy"]/li/a/@href').extract():
              // yield Request(response.urljoin(url), callback=self.parse)
              yield d
```

Comment: This should be so easy, use aux variable for highest and lowest, first time you read a value that will be the highest and the lowest, next time compare if you read value is bigger than highest set highest to read value. Same for lowest

Answer (score 0):

Build the dictionary before the yield statement.  This will let you reference the values already in the dictionary.

```
for courses in response.xpath("//meta"):
    d = {'courset1score': float(courses.xpath('//meta[@name="t1-score"]/@content').extract_first('').strip() or -1),
         'courset2score': float(courses.xpath('//meta[@name="t2-score"]/@content').extract_first('').strip() or -1),
         'courset3score': float(courses.xpath('//meta[@name="t3-score"]/@content').extract_first('').strip() or -1),
         'courset4score': float(courses.xpath('//meta[@name="t4-score"]/@content').extract_first('').strip() or -1),
         'courset5score': float(courses.xpath('//meta[@name="t5-score"]/@content').extract_first('').strip() or -1),
           }

    d['highestscore'] = max(d.values())
    d['lowestscore'] = min(d.values())
    yield d
```

Comment: There are some other text values as well like page URL and title, that I am capturing from the crawled page. Where do I put those values ? Please see updated code in question above. Thanks

Comment: add them to the dictionary after you have assigned `highestscore` and `lowestscore`

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question.  `yield d` will return the entire dictionary.

Comment: Yes, it does.  If the answer is complete, please remember to mark is so.

Comment: Thanks, not sure how it will crawl multiple pages then, without the `urljoin` and `callback=self.parse` function ?

Comment: Hi @James, This is not working. `pagetitle` and `pageurl` are outside dictionary ....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we have this html document example:

```
body = """
<meta name="t1-score" content="10"></meta>
<meta name="t2-score" content="20"></meta>
<meta name="t3-score" content="5"></meta>
<meta name="t4-score" content="8"></meta>
"""
sel = Selector(text=body)
```

We can extract scores, convert to number objects and use inbuilt `min` and `max` functions.

```
# you can use this xpath to select any score 
scores = sel.xpath("//meta[re:test(@name, 't\d-score')]/@content").extract()
# ['10', '20', '5', '8']
scores = [float(score) for score in scores]
# [10.0, 20.0, 5.0, 8.0]
min(scores)
# 5.0
max(scores)
# 20.0
```

Combining output:

```
item = dict()
item['max_score'] = max(scores)
item['min_score'] = min(scores)
for i, score in enumerate(scores):
    item['score{}'.format(i)] = score
```

Comment: Thanks @Granitosaurus Can I do this in `yield` statement ? Its not just `scores` I need to pick up, there are some other fields as well like `pagetitle` and `url` etc .... How do I put it all together ? Sorry, a Python noob here ....

Comment: Seems like you're missing a lot of the basic knowledge. I'd suggest investing few hours and do [scrapy tutorial](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html). Questions on stackoverflow should really focus on one problem so it's difficult to provide more than one answer. I'd say try to understand what's the flow of scrapy: requests, callbacks, items etc. and then come back with a new question. Sorry if it comes out as a turn-down but it's a faster way to learn than trying to glue bits of knowledge :)

Comment: Thanks @Granitosaurus, Its just 1 question I have asked. How do I do some processing on some specific fields i.e. finding (lowest/highest values) before yielding ? Sorry, If I was not clear enough earlier. And I have already spent some hours on Scrapy, Python and Beautiful Soup tutorials.

Comment: First you should create a empty dictionary object. Then you can create variables and mold the data the way you want it before yielding or returning a dictionary. Just like the last bit of my code. You can also do post-processing in scrapy pipelines or itemloaders.